# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (fixProperties)

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

Unable to compile as it throws an compilation error

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (fixProperties) on project flin-web-core: An Ant BuildException has occurred: Nothing to replace expression with.
around Ant part ...... @ 4:42

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>fixProperties</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <replaceregexp byline="true" flags="g">
                        <regexp pattern="([^'])'([^'])" />
                        <substitution expression="\1''\2" />
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources"> 
                            <include name="ApplicationResources_*.properties" /> 
                        </fileset>
                    </replaceregexp>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

StackTrace

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run
>   (fixProperties) on project flin-web-core: An Ant BuildException has
>   occured:
>   C:\petprojects\system\system\trunk\flin-web-core\target\generated-sources
>   does not exist. around Ant part ...... @ 4:42 in
>   C:\petprojects\system\system\trunk\flin-web-core\target\antrun\build-main.xml
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant
>   BuildException has occured:
>   C:\petprojects\system\system\trunk\flin-web-core\target\generated-sources
>   does not exist. around Ant part ...... @ 4:42 in
>   C:\petprojects\system\system\trunk\flin-web-core\target\antrun\build-main.xml
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:342)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>           ... 19 more Caused by: C:\petprojects\system\system\trunk\glin-web-core\target\antrun\build-main.xml:4:
>   C:\petprojects\system\system\trunk\glin-web-core\target\generated-sources
>   does not exist.
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.types.AbstractFileSet.getDirectoryScanner(AbstractFileSet.java:484)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet.iterator(FileSet.java:69)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union.getAllResources(Union.java:148)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union.getCollection(Union.java:108)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.BaseResourceCollectionContainer.cacheCollection(BaseResourceCollectionContainer.java:263)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.BaseResourceCollectionContainer.iterator(BaseResourceCollectionContainer.java:142)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ReplaceRegExp.execute(ReplaceRegExp.java:548)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:313)
>           ... 21 more [ERROR] [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the
>   build with the command [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :flin-web-core